# Laravel 5.2 : Accessing relationship method from the other relationship method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i am trying to access the relationship in laravel relationship from other relation of my Entity model but i am getting a wrong return.

```
class Entity{


public function company()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Company' , 'company_code' , 'company_code' );
}

public function branch(){
    $company = $this->company; // wrong return
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Branch' , 'company_code' , 'company_code' )
        ->where( 'company_id' , $company->company_id );
}

public function getTestAttribute(){
    $company = $this->company // correct return
    return $company->company_id;
}
```

The `$this->company` is returning the first item of company model instead of its relationship when i am trying to access it on my `branch()` method. Is there a way to access `company()` method in other relationship method with a correct value? I can access it on my Accessor method so i am expecting to access it too.

Answer (score 2):

I think that laravel call relation ship methods when the app started to define relation between tables,  during this time `$this` reference nothing, I suggest you to move `branch` relation to the `Company` model:

```
class Company{

    public function branch() {

        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Branch' , 'company_code' , 'company_code' );

    }

}
```

Now you can get `branch` from the `Entity` by using:

```
$this->company()->branch
```

Comment: I appreciate  the suggestion. but company models has `branches()` method on it. I cannot make `branch()` with `hasOne()` because company  `hasMany()` branches under it. I cannot adjust relationship this time. However, If there is no way. I think i have to make a query builder to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the condition in following way -

```
public function branch(){
    $companyId = $this->company->company_id;
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Branch' , 'company_code' , 'company_code' )
        ->where( 'company_id', '=', $companyId );
}
```

Comment: Already tried this. Since the `$this->company` returns a first row from the database when i am accessing it on `branch()` method, it is giving me a wrong set of data. So company_id returns 1 instead of 52.